# How do I get composite subclass to display in Java SWT

Tags: java, swt, subclass, composite

I'm making a game which uses various different screens within one shell and I'm trying to change the screen by using composite subclasses in SWT, however when the code is run, none of the widgets added to the subclass are showing.

Main code which calls the composite -

```
         Button newGameButton = new Button(startComposite, SWT.PUSH);
    FormData fd_newGameButton = new FormData();
    fd_newGameButton.left = new FormAttachment(0, 296);
    newGameButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));
    newGameButton.setText("New Game");
    newGameButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
            if (fullScreen == true) {
                startComposite.dispose();
                shell.setFullScreen(true);
            } else {
                startComposite.dispose();
            }

            GameComposite gameComposite = new GameComposite(shell, SWT.NONE);
            gameComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
            gameComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        }

        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
            if (fullScreen == true) {
                startComposite.dispose();
                shell.setFullScreen(true);
            } else {
                startComposite.dispose();
            }

            GameComposite gameComposite = new GameComposite(shell, SWT.NONE);
            gameComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
            gameComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

And this is the subclass code -

```
     public class GameComposite extends Composite {
private Text text;

/**
 * Create the composite.
 * @param parent
 * @param style
 */
public GameComposite(Composite parent, int style) {
    super(parent, style);

    Group gamePanel = new Group(this, SWT.NONE);
    gamePanel.setText("GamePanel1");
    gamePanel.setBounds(518, 10, 196, 502);

    text = new Text(this, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setEditable(false);
    text.setBounds(10, 418, 285, 94);


}

@Override
protected void checkSubclass() {
    // Disable the check that prevents subclassing of SWT components
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to call `layout()` after setting the layout. This should probably be done in the constructor, unless you actually want to use several different layouts for your `GameComposite`.
2. You are allowed to subclass `Composite`, so there is no need to override `checkSubclass` (and it's a bad habit!)

Comment: sorry, I'm totally new at GUI coding, only started my 1st semester at college! how would I call layout? in the subclass?

Comment: `this.setLayout(...)` or just `setLayout(...)`.

Comment: it is already done here -

 GameComposite gameComposite = new GameComposite(shell, SWT.NONE);
            gameComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
            gameComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

Comment: Yes, and as I said, this _should_ be done in constructor, unless you want to call these methods each time after creating a `GameComposite`. But that's just advice on how to improve your code. The important part is that after setting the layout you should also call the game composite's `layout()` method. And since you changed game composite's layout data, you also need to call its parent's `layout()` method as well.